# How to filter files based on a given particular date using DIR command in Windows Batch Script?

Tags: windows, date, batch-file, filter, directory

I have created windows batch script to create zip file and move from source to destination based on the given date as parameter as follows:

> C:>MkeAndMve_file.bat sourcepath destinationpath output.zip 1/25/2017

I can do create zip and move. but I cannot filter based on the given date. I am using the following script to do this,

```
@echo off &setlocal

set "sourceFolder=C:\Users\1545280\Documents\Mohan_J\SOURCE1"
set "cabFolder=C:\Users\1545280\Documents\Mohan_J\DESTINATION1"
set "cabName=my.cab"
set dt="1/25/2017"
call :mkCab "%sourceFolder%" "%cabFolder%" "%cabName%"

pause
goto :eof


:mkCab
:: change working directory
pushd "%temp%"
:: define variables in .ddf file
>directives.ddf echo .Option Explicit
>>directives.ddf echo .Set SourceDir="%~1"
>>directives.ddf echo .Set DiskDirectoryTemplate="%~2"
>>directives.ddf echo .Set CabinetNameTemplate="%~3"
>>directives.ddf echo .Set MaxDiskSize=0
>>directives.ddf echo .Set CabinetFileCountThreshold=0
>>directives.ddf echo .Set UniqueFiles=OFF
>>directives.ddf echo .Set Cabinet=ON
>>directives.ddf echo .Set Compress=ON
>>directives.ddf echo .Set CompressionType=MSZIP
>>directives.ddf echo .Set DestinationDir="%~n1"
:: save current ASCII code page
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%i in ('chcp') do set /a oemcp=%%~ni
:: change code page to ANSI
chcp 1252>nul
:: append all file names of the source folder
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /a-d /b "%~1"') do (
::for /f "delims=" %%i in ('forfiles /P "%1%" /D "%dt%"') do (
  >>directives.ddf echo "%%i"
)
:: process sub folders
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /ad /b "%~1"') do (
::for /f "delims=" %%i in ('forfiles /P "%1%" /D "%dt%"') do (
echo %%i

  >>directives.ddf echo .Set SourceDir="%~1\%%i"
  >>directives.ddf echo .Set DestinationDir="%~n1\%%i"
  for /f "delims=" %%j in ('dir /a-d /b "%~1\%%i"') do (  
::  for /f "delims=" %%j in ('forfiles /P "%~1\%%i" /D "%dt%"') do (
    >>directives.ddf echo "%%j"
  )

)
:: change back to ASCII
chcp %oemcp%>nul
:: call makecab
makecab /f directives.ddf
:: clean up
del setup.inf
del setup.rpt
del directives.ddf
:: return to the previous working directory
popd
goto :eof
```

How to filter files based on the given date

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /a-d /b "%~1"')
```

I tried as

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /a-d /b "%~1" ^| find "01/25/2017"')
```

But it does not work.Please help me to filter files based on the given date as parameter in the DIR Command as mentioned above

Comment: Hint: `dir /b` shows you the filename only. No **date**, no time, no attributes, no size... You can get the date/time with `%%~ta` (see `for /?` for more of those modifiers)

Comment: (File) date/time handling in `cmd`/[tag:batch-file] is terrible. You might use `wmic DataFile where (Name="D:\\folder\\filename.ext") get LastModified` in order to get a locale-independent date/time format. Commands like `date`/`time`, `dir` and `forfiles`, as well as `~t` modifiers, all rely on the region settings. You should clearly define whether or not you want to make your script independent. If not, you need to describe your current date/time format...